# Query LINQ doesn't work on variable string

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

simply put, this works:

```
Database db = DatabaseWrapper.GetDatabase();
string dd = e.ParsedData.Date.ToString("yyyyMMdd");
var todaysflights = db.Flights.GetList(x => x.ScheduleDateTime.Contains("20150413")).ToList();
```

But this doesn't,

```
Database db = DatabaseWrapper.GetDatabase();
string dd = e.ParsedData.Date.ToString("yyyyMMdd");
var todaysflights = db.Flights.GetList(x => x.ScheduleDateTime.Contains(dd)).ToList();
```

This is inside an event handler and I can guarantee you that when I print it to console the value in dd is exactly "20150413".

**UPDATE:**

The method GetList is working correctly because i get the expected results from and it returns a IEnumerable:

```
    var todaysflights = db.Flights.GetList(x =>     x.ScheduleDateTime.Contains("20150413")).ToList();
```

which is a list of flights for that date.

I am using Contains because the field ScheduleDateTime is like "20150413164500", not a DateTime. I could have used StartsWith as well but i believe that is not the problem.

When i say doesnt work i mean that when i run GetList with the variable "dd" i get an empty List while when with hard coded string "20150413" i get a List with 1868 results.

The value of dd when printed to console is exactly "20150413".

e.ParsedData has a bunch of Data parsed from a barcode reader and the Date property is of type DateTime, thats why e.ParsedData.Date.ToString("yyyyMMdd") gives me the format i want.

I am really sorry for the incomplete question, i was just leaving work when i wrote it.

Thank you guys for the fast reply.

**UPDATE 2**

I have been testing and the following code returns the expected result (a list with a bunch of data):

```
var dd = e.ParsedData.Date.ToString("yyyyMMdd");
        var todaysflights = _db.Flights.GetList(x => x.ScheduleDateTime.Contains(""+dd)).ToList();
```

Anyone can tell why does this ""+dd makes the expression give me the result expected not an empty List?

Thank you

Comment: If you've verified the input to your `GetList` custom function is correct, then the problem lies with that function. You'll have to provide the code for `GetList` if you want an answer that fixes your problem.

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't work? Exception? Incorrect results?

Comment: Does the value of dd return what you'd expect?

Comment: Please be more specific. Please provide [a good, _minimal_, _complete_ code example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that reliably reproduces the problem. Please be more specific about the problem than "this doesn't". State clearly what the code you have does, and how that is different from what you want it to do. Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for advice on how to present your question in a clear, answerable way.

Answer (score 0):

There is so much strange going on i the code.
i assume `GetList` returns a list so why `GetList().ToList()`
and the LINQ `x.ScheduleDateTime.Contains(dd)` what is `ScheduleDateTime`? a `string` or a `DateTime`? from your problem it is stated as a `string` but it name says `DateTime`. (lastly im assuming `e.ParsedData` is `DateTime` you can write `e.ParsedData.ToString("yyyyMMdd");` instead).

So based on what I am assuming the`GetList` actually returns a list and the `ScheduleDateTime` contains `DateTime`

So I would try comparing directly on datetime and not double the work on the list.

```
Database db = DatabaseWrapper.GetDatabase();
DateTime dd = e.ParsedData.Date;
var todaysflights = db.Flights.GetList(x => x.ScheduleDateTime.Date == dd);
```

If all else fails then throw it in a `foreach`. Then you can debug each loop nicely, alternately `try/catch`

```
Database db = DatabaseWrapper.GetDatabase();
DateTime dd = e.ParsedData.Date;
List<Flight> todaysflights = new List<Flight>();
foreach (var a in db.Flights.GetList()){
    try
    {
        if(a.ScheduleDateTime.Date() == dd){
            todaysflights.Add(a);
        }
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        //Print some caught error but don't break program
    }
}
```